# is _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks trusted

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

In below code snipped, We are allocation memory with new operator and releasing memory using free() function. Its wrong. [ Correct way to release memory use delete operator.]
Means memory leak present here. But _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() not printing memory leak.
Is it trusted way to check memory leak ?

```
int main()
{
    int* ptr = new int[5];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = (i + 1) * 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << ptr[i];
    }

     free(ptr);
    //delete ptr;
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Comment: On your platform, it appears `new[]` is implemented using `malloc`, so there is no leak.  (On my platform, `new`, `new[]` and `malloc` each have different heap arenas.  Which would cause a program fault if mix-n-matched.)

Comment: It's wrong, but that does not mean that memory was leaked (it could have been allocated with `malloc`). What it means is that your program has undefined behaviour.